# Elapsed time in R - min, max

Tags: r, elapsedtime

I need to compare two functions in terms of elapsed time. At the moment I am using the following code:

```
system.time(f1())
system.time(f2())
```

And if I want to run the same functions multiple times I use:

```
system.time(replicate(10, f1()))
system.time(replicate(10, f2()))
```

The information that I get from `system.time` is user, system and elapsed time.

The point is that I would know, if I replicate the function, also the min and max elapsed time of the single call.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not constrained by using only `base` packages, I would suggest using [microbenchmark](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/microbenchmark.pdf) package.

```
> f1 <- function() 1
> f2 <- function() 2
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times = 10)
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min  lq  mean median  uq  max neval cld
 f1() 134 195 896.7    309 360 6418    10   a
 f2() 133 138 305.3    189 230 1320    10   a
```

However, if you still want to use `system.time`, just move `replicate` outside of `system.time` call. For example,

```
> f1 <- function() sapply(1:100000, identity)
> times <- replicate(10, system.time(f1())[3])
> min(times)
[1] 0.051
> max(times)
[1] 0.057
```